# JavaScript Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe: Need help clearing game board

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe game. Everything works except for when I try to clear the board when I press Play Again. All the small squares clear but if there is a winner in a large square then it does not clear when I press Play Again. How can I fix this? I apologize in advance if my coding is bad, I have very little experience with this.

Here is the link to the game. You can Inspect to see the code. I couldn't attach it because it exceeded the character limit.

https://bryantfiallos.github.io/pset-9/ultimate.html

This is my js

```js
///////////////////// CONSTANTS /////////////////////////////////////
const winningConditions = [
  [0, 10, 20],
  [30, 40, 50],
  [60, 70, 80],
  [0, 30, 60],
  [10, 40, 70],
  [20, 50, 80],
  [0, 40, 80],
  [20, 40, 60]
];

const firstLeftWinConditions = [

  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [3, 6, 9],
  [1, 5, 9],
  [3, 5, 7]
]

const firstMiddleWinConditions = [

  [11, 12, 13],
  [14, 15, 16],
  [17, 18, 19],
  [11, 14, 17],
  [12, 15, 18],
  [13, 16, 19],
  [11, 15, 19],
  [13, 15, 17]
]

const firstRightWinConditions = [

  [21, 22, 23],
  [24, 25, 26],
  [27, 28, 29],
  [21, 24, 27],
  [22, 25, 28],
  [23, 26, 29],
  [21, 25, 29],
  [23, 25, 27]
]

const secondLeftWinConditions = [

  [31, 32, 33],
  [34, 35, 36],
  [37, 38, 39],
  [31, 34, 37],
  [32, 35, 38],
  [33, 36, 39],
  [31, 35, 39],
  [33, 35, 37]
]

const secondMiddleWinConditions = [

  [41, 42, 43],
  [44, 45, 46],
  [47, 48, 49],
  [41, 44, 47],
  [42, 45, 48],
  [43, 46, 49],
  [41, 45, 49],
  [43, 45, 47]
]

const secondRightWinConditions = [

  [51, 52, 53],
  [54, 55, 56],
  [57, 58, 59],
  [51, 54, 57],
  [52, 55, 58],
  [53, 56, 59],
  [51, 55, 59],
  [53, 55, 57]
]

const thirdLeftWinConditions = [

  [61, 62, 63],
  [64, 65, 66],
  [67, 68, 69],
  [61, 64, 67],
  [62, 65, 68],
  [63, 66, 69],
  [61, 65, 69],
  [63, 65, 67]
]

const thirdMiddleWinConditions = [

  [71, 72, 73],
  [74, 75, 76],
  [77, 78, 79],
  [71, 74, 77],
  [72, 75, 78],
  [73, 76, 79],
  [71, 75, 79],
  [73, 75, 77]
]

const thirdRightWinConditions = [

  [81, 82, 83],
  [84, 85, 86],
  [87, 88, 89],
  [81, 84, 87],
  [82, 85, 88],
  [83, 86, 89],
  [81, 85, 89],
  [83, 85, 87]
]
///////////////////// APP STATE (VARIABLES) /////////////////////////
let board;
let turn;
let win = false;
let xWins = 0;
let oWins = 0;
let ties = 0;
let first = "X"
let nextMove;
let gameWinner;
let currentSquare;
let firstLeftWin = false;
let firstMiddleWin = false;
let firstRightWin = false;
let secondLeftWin = false;
let secondMiddleWin = false;
let secondRightWin = false;
let thirdLeftWin = false;
let thirdMiddleWin = false;
let thirdRightWin = false;
let firstLeftWinner;
let firstMiddleWinner;
let firstRightWinner;
let secondLeftWinner;
let secondMiddleWinner;
let secondRightWinner;
let thirdLeftWinner;
let thirdMiddleWinner;
let thirdRightWinner;
///////////////////// CACHED ELEMENT REFERENCES /////////////////////
const squares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#board div"));
const message = document.querySelector("h2");
///////////////////// EVENT LISTENERS ///////////////////////////////
window.onload = init;
document.getElementById("board").onclick = takeTurn;
document.getElementById("reset-button").onclick = init;
document.getElementById("xFirst").onclick = xFirst;
document.getElementById("oFirst").onclick = oFirst;
document.getElementById("reset-scoreboard").onclick = resetScoreboard;
///////////////////// FUNCTIONS /////////////////////////////////////
function init() {
  for (x = 0; x < 90; x++) {
    if (x % 10 === 0) {

    } else {
      squares[x].textContent = "";
    }
  }

  board = [

  ];
document.getElementById("first-left").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("first-middle").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("first-right").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("second-left").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("second-middle").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("second-right").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("third-left").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("third-middle").classList.remove("nextSquare");
document.getElementById("third-right").classList.remove("nextSquare");


  turn = "X";
  nextMove = "any"
  render();
}

function render() {
  board.forEach(function(mark, index) {
    squares[index].textContent = mark;
  });

  message.textContent =
    win === "T" ? "It's a tie!" : win ? `${win} wins!` : `Turn: ${turn}`;
}

function takeTurn(e) {
  if (!win) {
    let index = squares.findIndex(function(square) {
      return square === e.target;
    });

console.log(index);

  if (nextMove == "any") {
    if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
      board[index] = turn;
      turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
      win = getWinner();
      nextMove = getNextMove(e);
      if (win === "T") {
        ties++;
        document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
      }

      render();
    }
  }




  else if (nextMove == "firstleft") {
    if (board[0] != "X" && board[0] != "O" && board[0] != "T") {


    if (index >= 1 && index <= 9) {
    if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
      board[index] = turn;
      turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
      win = getWinner();
      firstLeftWinner = getFirstLeftWinner(e);
      nextMove = getNextMove(e);
      document.getElementById("first-left").classList.remove("nextSquare");
      nextMove = getNextMove(e);

      if (win === "T") {
        ties++;
        document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
      }

      render();
    }
  }
}
  else {
    nextMove = "any"
  }
}


else if (nextMove == "firstmiddle") {
  if (board[10] != "X" && board[10] != "O" && board[10] != "T") {


  if (index >= 11 && index <= 19) {
  if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    firstMiddleWinner = getFirstMiddleWinner();

    document.getElementById("first-middle").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}

}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}


else if (nextMove == "firstright") {
  if (board[20] != "X" && board[20] != "O" && board[20] != "T") {


  if (index >= 21 && index <= 29) {
  if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    firstRightWinner = getFirstRightWinner();

    document.getElementById("first-right").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}

}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}



else if (nextMove == "secondleft") {
  if (board[30] != "X" && board[30] != "O" && board[30] != "T") {


  if (index >= 31 && index <= 39 ) {
  if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    secondLeftWinner = getSecondLeftWinner();

    document.getElementById("second-left").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}

}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}


else if (nextMove == "secondmiddle") {
  if (board[40] != "X" && board[40] != "O" && board[40] != "T") {
    document.getElementById("second-middle").classList.add("nextSquare");


  if (index >= 41 && index <= 49) {
  if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    secondMiddleWinner = getSecondMiddleWinner();

    document.getElementById("second-middle").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}
}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}


else if (nextMove == "secondright") {
  if (board[50] != "X" && board[50] != "O" && board[50] != "T") {


  if (index >= 51 && index <= 59) {
  if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    secondRightWinner = getSecondRightWinner();

    document.getElementById("second-right").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}
}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}


else if (nextMove == "thirdleft") {
  if (board[60] != "X" && board[60] != "O" && board[60] != "T") {


  if (index >= 61 && index <= 69) {
  if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    thirdLeftWinner = getThirdLeftWinner();

    document.getElementById("third-left").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}
}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}


else if (nextMove == "thirdmiddle") {
  if (board[70] != "X" && board[70] != "O" && board[70] != "T") {


  if (index >= 71 && index <= 79) {
    if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    thirdMiddleWinner = getThirdMiddleWinner();

    document.getElementById("third-middle").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}
}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}


else if (nextMove == "thirdright") {
  if (board[80] != "X" && board[80] != "O" && board[80] != "T") {


  if (index >= 81 && index <= 89) {
  if (squares[index].textContent === "") {
    board[index] = turn;
    turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    win = getWinner();
    thirdRightWinner = getThirdRightWinner();

    document.getElementById("third-right").classList.remove("nextSquare");
    nextMove = getNextMove(e);
    if (win === "T") {
      ties++;
      document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    }

    render();
  }
}
}
else {
  nextMove = "any"
}
}

else {
  return false;
}

win = getWinner();
render();
  }
}

function getWinner() {
  let winner = null;

  winningConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {

    if (
      board[condition[0]] &&
      board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
      board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]

    ) {
      winner = board[condition[0]];
      win = winner;
      if (winner === "X") {
        xWins++;
        document.getElementById("xScore").innerHTML = xWins;
        playYuh();
      }
      else if (winner === "O") {
        oWins++;
        document.getElementById("oScore").innerHTML = oWins;
        playYuh();
      }

    }

  });

  if (!winner && board[0] != undefined && board[10] != undefined && board[20] != undefined && board[30] != undefined && board[40] != undefined && board[50] != undefined && board[60] != undefined && board[70] != undefined && board[80] != undefined) {
    winner = "T";
    win = winner;


  }

  return winner ? winner : board.includes(undefined) ? null : "T";
}

function xFirst(){
  init();
  document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Turn: X";
  turn = "X";
  first = "X"

}
function oFirst(){
  init();
  document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Turn: O";
  turn = "O";
  first = "O"
}


function resetScoreboard() {
    xWins = 0;
    oWins = 0;
    ties = 0;

    document.getElementById("xScore").innerHTML = xWins;
    document.getElementById("tScore").innerHTML = ties;
    document.getElementById("oScore").innerHTML = oWins;
}

function playYuh() {
  document.getElementById("myAudio").play();
}

function getNextMove(e) {

  let index = squares.findIndex(function(square) {
    return square === e.target;
  });

  if (index % 10 == 1) {
    if (board[0] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "firstleft"
      document.getElementById("first-left").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[0] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }

  }


  if (index % 10 == 2) {
    if (board[10] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "firstmiddle"
      document.getElementById("first-middle").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[10] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }


  if (index % 10 == 3) {
    if (board[20] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "firstright"
      document.getElementById("first-right").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[20] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }


  if (index % 10 == 4) {
    if (board[30] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "secondleft"
      document.getElementById("second-left").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[30] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }



  if (index % 10 == 5) {
    if (board[40] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "secondmiddle"
      document.getElementById("second-middle").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[40] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }


  if (index % 10 == 6) {
    if (board[50] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "secondright"
      document.getElementById("second-right").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[50] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }


  if (index % 10 == 7) {
    if (board[60] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "thirdleft"
      document.getElementById("third-left").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[60] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }


  if (index % 10 == 8) {
    if (board[70] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "thirdmiddle"
      document.getElementById("third-middle").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[70] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }


  if (index % 10 == 9) {
    if (board[80] == undefined) {
      nextMove = "thirdright"
      document.getElementById("third-right").classList.add("nextSquare");
    }
    else if (board[80] != undefined) {
      nextMove = "any";

    }


  }

  return nextMove;

}


function getFirstLeftWinner(e) {
let firstLeftWin = false;
  firstLeftWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  firstLeftWin = true;
  firstLeftWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[0] = winner;
}
});

if (!firstLeftWin && board[1] != undefined && board[2] != undefined && board[3] != undefined && board[4] != undefined && board[5] != undefined && board[6] != undefined && board[7] != undefined && board[8] != undefined && board[9] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  firstLeftWinner = winner;
  board[0] = winner;

}

}


function getFirstMiddleWinner() {
  let firstMiddleWin = false;

  firstMiddleWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  firstMiddleWin = true;
  firstMiddleWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[10] = winner;
}
});

if (!firstMiddleWin && board[11] != undefined && board[12] != undefined && board[13] != undefined && board[14] != undefined && board[15] != undefined && board[16] != undefined && board[17] != undefined && board[18] != undefined && board[19] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  firstMiddleWinner = winner;
  board[10] = winner;

}

}


function getFirstRightWinner() {
  let firstRightWin = false;

  firstRightWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  firstRightWin = true;
  firstRightWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[20] = winner;
}
});

if (!firstRightWin && board[21] != undefined && board[22] != undefined && board[23] != undefined && board[24] != undefined && board[25] != undefined && board[26] != undefined && board[27] != undefined && board[28] != undefined && board[29] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  firstRightWinner = winner;
  board[20] = winner;

}

}


function getSecondLeftWinner() {
  secondLeftWin = false;

  secondLeftWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  secondLeftWin = true;
  secondLeftWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[30] = winner;
}
});

if (!secondLeftWin && board[31] != undefined && board[32] != undefined && board[33] != undefined && board[34] != undefined && board[35] != undefined && board[36] != undefined && board[37] != undefined && board[38] != undefined && board[39] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  secondLeftWinner = winner;
  board[30] = winner;

}

}


function getSecondMiddleWinner() {
let secondMiddleWin = false;
  secondMiddleWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  secondMiddleWin = true;
  secondMiddleWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[40] = winner;
}

});

if (!secondMiddleWin && board[41] != undefined && board[42] != undefined && board[43] != undefined && board[44] != undefined && board[45] != undefined && board[46] != undefined && board[47] != undefined && board[48] != undefined && board[49] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  secondMiddleWinner = winner;
  board[40] = secondMiddleWinner;

}
return secondMiddleWinner;
}


function getSecondRightWinner() {

let secondRightWin = false;
  secondRightWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  secondRightWin = true;
  secondRightWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[50] = winner;
}
});

if (!secondRightWin && board[51] != undefined && board[52] != undefined && board[53] != undefined && board[54] != undefined && board[55] != undefined && board[56] != undefined && board[57] != undefined && board[58] != undefined && board[59] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  secondRightWinner = winner;
  board[50] = secondRightWinner;
  console.log("issa tie");

}

}


function getThirdLeftWinner() {
  let thirdLeftWin = false;

  thirdLeftWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  thirdLeftWin = true;
  thirdLeftWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[60] = winner;
}
});

if (!thirdLeftWin && board[61] != undefined && board[62] != undefined && board[63] != undefined && board[64] != undefined && board[65] != undefined && board[66] != undefined && board[67] != undefined && board[68] != undefined && board[69] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  thirdLeftWinner = winner;
  board[60] = winner;

}

}


function getThirdMiddleWinner() {
  let thirdMiddleWin = false;

  thirdMiddleWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  thirdMiddleWin = true;
  thirdMiddleWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[70] = winner;
}
});

if (!thirdMiddleWin && board[71] != undefined && board[72] != undefined && board[73] != undefined && board[74] != undefined && board[75] != undefined && board[76] != undefined && board[77] != undefined && board[78] != undefined && board[79] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  thirdMiddleWinner = winner;
  board[70] = winner;

}

}


function getThirdRightWinner() {
  let thirdRightWin = false;

  thirdRightWinConditions.forEach(function(condition, index) {
  if (
    board[condition[0]] &&
    board[condition[0]] === board[condition[1]] &&
    board[condition[1]] === board[condition[2]]
  ) {

  winner = board[condition[0]];
  thirdRightWin = true;
  thirdRightWinner = winner;
  console.log("LOCAL WINNER 1");
  board[80] = winner;
}
});

if (!thirdLeftWin && board[81] != undefined && board[82] != undefined && board[83] != undefined && board[84] != undefined && board[85] != undefined && board[86] != undefined && board[87] != undefined && board[88] != undefined && board[89] != undefined) {
  winner = "T";
  thirdRightWinner = winner;
  board[80] = winner;

}

}
```

Comment: Buddy you might wanna use a loop instead of making a function and a variable for every square. The approach you've taken will only cause you immense pain in the future.

Comment: And wow, is that background distracting.

Comment: Show your code. Thats what we read here. Your description in text is cool but on same token you yourself admit that things are going wrong. 
Only source code will reveal the errors. If you could update your post with your source code ( **what you have try** ) it would be highly productive in someone finding the bug. Also please read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yup like @fubar say. the background will bring a bad experience to the user. I not mean to hurt your feeling, but it is what it is. you should use more ***peaceful*** background. ;)

Comment: I feel really bad for your JS code, And honestly can't wait the day you'll realize you've could have built this one in less than 80 lines of JS :)

Comment: What are those arrays like `winningConditions` representing?

Comment: PS: I got stuck at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpxVz.png - unsolvable, since no player could set any symbol in a square. Not to mention that randomly there's no "next" field... Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you click 'Play Again', init() is being called and that function only clears the value of all of the child cells in each big block. The problem is, when someone wins the block, you're getting rid of all of those children and just replacing it with a 'X', 'O' or 'T'. I.e. there are no longer child cells to clear.

More of an approach issue than a code issue.

You want to either regenerate those cells in init() if they don't exist, or just use an overlay to display the winner of each block which you can easily remove in init()

Comment: How can I regenerate those cells in init() ?

Comment: For each completed cell, remove the text (X, O or T), create a for loop with 9 iterations and you can use `var el = document.createElement("div");` then `el.setAttribute('class', 'mini-square');` and insert each new div with `document.getElementById('first-left').appendChild(el);`